# Emulate DocumentRoot in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Say we cannot change DocumentRoot. (Trying to get Silex working in one.com)

Is there a way to get around this?

my setup:

root / .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

root / web / .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This sadly doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you specify little bit more what exactly you want? I mean to say which url you want to rewrite in which format just one example will be sufficient.

Comment: After `RewriteEngine On` add this line in `root/.htaccess`: `RewriteBase /` and add this line in `root/web/.htaccess`: `RewriteBase /web/`

Comment: @ prashantthakre all of them ofcourse. @justin-iurman doesn't work :(

Comment: @JustinIurman It actually does work :) looked like Varnish cached the error page -.-